# Using xrandr when starting new xserver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, systemd, xrandr

I'm trying to set the resolution and refresh rate of a screen when i launch an application on a new xserver.

The xrandr commands i usually use to get this screen to work are:

```
 xrandr --newmode 2560x1440 146.27 2560 2680 2944 3328 1440 1441 1444 1465 -HSync +Vsync
 xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440
 xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440
 xrandr --output LVDS1 --off
```

The command i am using to start the xserver is

```
 xinit /usr/bin/urbanterror $* -- :1
```

**Here is what i have tried so far**

I think i need to put these xrandr settings in a xorg config file and pass it in:

```
 xinit /usr/bin/urbanterror $* -- :1 -xf86config xorg.conf
```

I'm really unsure on how to do write the conf file to replicate these settings, the closest i have found is at the bottom of this
[webpage](http://fluxbox-wiki.org/category/howtos/en/Change_resolution.html), but i feel that it is incomplete.

I have also tried putting the xrandr commands in a script using that as the program to be started in the new xserver.

```
 xinit /home/user/.urtrc $* -- :1
```

with .urtrc containing

```
 #!/bin/sh

 xrandr --newmode 2560x1440 146.27 2560 2680 2944 3328 1440 1441 1444 1465 -HSync +Vsync
 xrandr --addmode HDMI1 2560x1440
 xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 2560x1440
 xrandr --output LVDS1 --off

 exec urbanterror
```

This worked, but the performance was aweful, i was barely getting 3fps on the lowest settings. I have no idea why.

Any help would be much  appreciated.

**Update**

Running glxgears in the new xserver gives these 2 errors:

```
 libGL error: failed to open drm device: Permission denied
 libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
```

So i know it's a permission problem. The script with the xrandr commands runs fine when run from root, and glxgears reports no errors. However i really don't want to have to run this as root for a number of reasons.

Before systemd this problem was solved by adding the user to group video. However after systemd there is no video group.

Any help on fixing those 2 errors would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `.utrc` file looks like it would work fine. Maybe OpenGL isn’t getting enabled when you start X this way?

Comment: I think you're right. I rendering manager for sure doesn't start, and i think opengl relies on that, not 100% sure. So it's a permissions problem now.

Comment: Do you have some other way of starting X that works? My impression is that you exit X and then start a new X session with your game as the only client. Also, systemd is my arch nemesis.

Comment: My Arch system has a `video` group and systemd. Maybe try adding the group and see if it does anything?